# Oracle Apex- How to increase font size of data in Interactive grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid and want to increase the default font size.

The column headers shall remain as it is, just the data in the cells inside the grid need to be changed.

Apex version is 20.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- navigate to page's property palette
- find the Inline CSS property
- put this into it:

  ```
  .a-GV-cell 
    { font-size: 30px !important;
    }
  ```
- run the page

Of course, modify font size to any value you find appropriate; `30px` is just an example.